# ADA static library - compatibility with different versions of compilers

Tags: static-libraries, ada

I have built a ADA static library and I share it by providing '.a' and ALI files.

Everything works fine while I use the same GNAT compiler version than the one used to build the static library.

But with another compiler version, the ALI files are considered as not valid (the compiler version is stored in all ALI files), and the compiler needs source files to rebuild ALI files.

Is there a solution to avoid this problem ?

**updated on 12/11/2015** : We did some tests (with ALI library files in ready only), but we still have the following errors :

```
error: "package1.adb" and "prog.adb" compiled    with different GNAT versions
error: "prog.adb" must be recompiled ("system.ads" has been modified)
```

So, I think we have to use the same compiler version for the library and the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from AdaCore :

*This isn't supported: the Ada ABI (Application Binary Interface) is not guaranteed to stay the same across versions (and indeed does change regularly), so you cannot mix objects compiled with different versions of GNAT, you really need to ensure consistency in all your libraries.*

So, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnatmake, make the ALI files read-only, so that the compiler does not try to recompile them (you are of course responsible for ensure that the object files are compatible, but this is in general the case).

If you are using project files, add a

```
for Externally_Built use "True";
```

attribute to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using the Externally_Built attribute in my library project. I will try the trick to make ALI files read-only.

Comment: If you are using a library project, you should take a look at "standalone libraries" then, in the gprbuild documentation. These might work better in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my initial post. A standalone library is not really a solution for us...